# Subobject classifiers in categories of smooth spaces

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

In "Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes" (chapter 23), by Mclarty, as well as "A Primer of Infintesimal Analysis" by Bell, the authors describe various axioms which a topos may satisfy in order to support synthetic differential geometry. In other words, they describe "toposes of smooth spaces". I am not sure if this appeal makes sense, but I am wondering if somebody could give me some intuition about what the subobject classifier $\Omega$ "looks like" in such a topos of smooth spaces. Are there cases where $\Omega$ looks similar to some familiar real manifold ? I am aware that there are various different toposes which can support the axioms of synthetic differential geometry, so perhaps my question is too vague. But I am finding it challenging to get to grips with the technical details of toposes of smooth spaces, and would be very grateful if somebody could help me get a mental picture of $\Omega$ within a category of smooth spaces. I do not know if this question makes sense, and whether $\Omega$ can be easily visualized as a space with a specific structure, but I thought it worth asking, since understanding more about $\Omega$ could help me within my early steps into synthetic differential geometry.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with synthetic differential geometry - so would one example of such a topos be the category of sheaves on the infinitesimal site, where an object of the infinitesimal site of a scheme $X$ would be an open subscheme $U \subseteq X$ along with a closed embedding $U \to Y$ defined by a nilpotent ideal sheaf on $Y$?  In that case, you would just be looking at a special case of the general $\Omega$ on a site topos, $\Omega(U)$ being the set of subsheaves of $h_U, V \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(V, U)$.

Comment: The subobject classifier is not a very nice “space”. Applying the definition, you see it can only have 2 points; and yet, it must have infinitely many loops, because the circle has infinitely many distinct submanifolds.